# Why is my system image of win7 only 25G if C: has 60G of data?

Tags: windows-7, system-restore

maybe it's a basic question but I was surprised by this.

My partition C: says it has 60GB of used space, but the windows image folder is only 25GB. Is windows keeping only relevant information, and will this allow me to a full restore if the drive dies and is replaced ?

Thank you

PS. I used Create a system image, under Backup and Restore in windows 7, shown here

[image]

Comment: I don't have *direct knowledge* of windows image backup (if this is the feature you describe), but I suspect that "winsxs" (Windows Side-by-Side) may be responsible for the discrepancy. Winsxs is a "magic folder" with multiple symbolic links (or similar) to a single actual file and Windows Explorer tends to double-count file sizes resulting in a higher "used space" calculation than is actually in use. Actually, it will count a file as many times as there are links to it, so it can be much more than double-counting. A virtual HDD file size report would not suffer from this inaccuracy.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did (right click on C: / properties). If I select all folders in C: / right click / properties, the size is 28.6G. My backup folder is 25.3G. So is this normal then ?

Comment: @Ramhound What should I use instead then. This is an important system exposed to high temperatures

Comment: What does it being exposed to high temperatures have to do with the amount of space Windows uses?

Comment: No, based on your and other comments, I suppose the image is correct. But you mentioned that it wont restore the system to previous state. Should I post another question about this ?

Comment: @Ramhound Can you post your comment as an answer. I think your idea explains the discrepancy.

Comment: @alfred - My comment wasn't 100% accurate.  So I won't be submitting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The System Image utility does make a complete copy of the drive in question. However, there are a couple things you have to remember. The first is that the utility uses compression on the files that are on the drive. For some files, like executables and image files, the compressed size will not be much smaller than the full size. For other files, like text files and Office documents, the compressed size can be much smaller than the original uncompressed size.

The second thing to keep in mind is that used space is not necessarily used space. There are times when files will be created of a certain size, but the contents of the file will be much smaller, leaving most of the file empty. When the utility compresses the file, it skips over most of the empty file space. The Windows system drive usually contains two files used by Windows that, depending on current state and your system settings, will often take up much more file space on the drive than the data actually in the file.

The first is the Page file (pagefile.sys). This file is used to swap data in and out of the computer's RAM onto the hard drive so the system can keep more apps open. The other is the Hibernation file (hiberfil.sys). This file is used to store the current state of the computer's RAM onto the hard drive when the computer enters hibernation mode. These are often the two biggest files on a Win7 system. And if they're mostly empty, your system image ends up being much smaller than the "used space" of the drive.

Comment: Actually, the WIndows System Image does not directly store the page file and hibernation file.  Both just get recreated at the appropriate size when you restore the image.

Comment: Ah, my memory was a bit hazy on those two. So if they're not stored at all, that can often explain a huge difference in sizes as those two files are usually the two biggest on the drive.